# Display all Contributions with event, membership etc details

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, drupal-views

Excuse me if I'm probably missing something obvious here...
Civi 4.6.18, Drupal 7.44

I want to build a simple report that shows:
Contribution fields, Contact name, Event name (if it came from an event), Membership type (if it came from a membership), etc. In one row.

Our finance team want to see all payments every month, and want to quickly see exactly what each payment was for.

It doesn't matter if some fields are blank - eg if membership fields are blank in a row that is about an event contribution.

I can't see a way to do this in Civi Reports, so turned to Views starting with the Contribution entity.

But I can't see a way to create a relationship to Participants in Views.

And I can make a relationship to memberships, but only if the payment is recurring. That doesn't cover all our membership possibilities.

Surely this would be a fairly standard report, so I'm wondering what to do? Thanks for your help!

**24-8-16: Editing this to add more info:**

If you create a View based on Civirm Contributions, in fact Membership details are in the fields available to the View. So that's half the story.

However, Participation fields are not available. Neither can you add a relationship to anything that looks like Civicrm Event tables. This is so after adding a relationship to the Contact ID.

So, if payments are made for events, there is no way to link the contribution to the event it is for, if you are starting from the Contribution table.

And if that is possible, the next question would be (with the advent of partial payment processing), if a part payment is made for an event, is there a way in Views to see the individual part payments?

If there was a bridge from the contribution table to event table(s) then we'd have our solution: a View that can show what payments are being made for, if they are membership or participant contributions.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you create a view starting as CiviCRM Contacts and then create a View Relationship to CiviCRM Contributions: Contact ID, does that help any?  You could get Amount, Financial Type, Date, etc.?

Comment: Allen, thanks for that thought. I was able to easily create a view that shows membership info this way; membership fields became available as soon as I added the relationship to contributions as you suggested. Excellent!

However, there's still no way I can see to create a relationship to Participant info. Participant fields didn't become available when I added the Contributions relationship. And there's no sign of a new relationship to participants. 

So it looks like we simply need an extra relationship added to the Civicrm Views integration to make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do when looking for more reporting functionality is to add:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports

That extension will give you a lot more and a lot more detailes reports to work with!

If you still can't get all the details you'd like in it - then you'll need to make some edits in code (create a fork of this extension).

Comment: Hmmm... I looked in this excellent extension, but it is similarly limited. I'm not a coder, so that's not an easy option. Also, I am surprised that Drupal Views doesn't provide a relationship from the participant record to the contribution table... So just wondering if I'm missing anything totally obvious. :)

Comment: Have you tried Civicrm Entity as Allen suggests?

Comment: Yes, the Civicrm Entity module is brilliant! But it too doesn't seem to provide links between contributions and events, and contributions and memberships (except via recurring contributions, which doesn't apply to all memberships as I mention above).

Comment: Hit Edit on your Question and show us how you're setting up your View - you've got a lot of eyes here - to help you figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [CiviCRM Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) provides you with the ability to connect a large number of CiviCRM entities (including Contributions) to Drupal.  That then makes them available to Views as fields, filters and relationships.

Comment: As mentioned above, we are using the Civicrm Entity module, but it doesn't look like it's quite done this extra mile. Brilliant though it is!